# Getting an Oculus Rift DK2 set up with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, monitor

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed and recently got an Oculus Rift DK2. While I have been able to use it as a monitor, I have yet to install any rift-related software because I do not know what to install. What do I need to install and how do I install it in order to get this working?

Comment: I also posted on reddit since I'm having trouble getting started too: http://www.reddit.com/r/oculus/comments/2rjklz/ubuntu_i_got_an_oculus_but_where_do_i_get_started/

Answer (score 4):

This article gives you full step-by-step instructions on how to get it set up, including which software to get from where and how to install and use it: https://support.oculus.com/hc/en-us/articles/202741283-Getting-Started-with-your-new-Oculus-Rift-Development-Kit-2